# Assign a unique value to a new column based on conditions

Tags: python, r

I have a dataset that summarises car trips, but it does not identify how many unique cars there are. I would like to create a loop/if statement that assigns a unique number based on a location and time a trip starts to figure out an approximate unique number of cars.

So for example, if dropoff location of the first car matches pickup location of the second car, and time frame is within 2 minutes, assign the same car number as the first car. If completely different assign a new number.

I tried different options but can't make it work(a beginner). Any help at this time is greatly appreciated. (R or Python)

This is roughly what I have:

| Pickup time | Dropoff time | Pickup location | Dropoff location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-06-09 21:06:36 | 2016-06-09 21:13:08 | A | B |
| 2016-06-09 21:13:31 | 2016-06-09 21:23:59 | A | C |
| 2016-06-09 21:13:45 | 2016-06-09 21:26:29 | B | C |
| 2016-06-09 21:15:33 | 2016-06-09 21:44:31 | A | B |
| 2016-06-09 21:24:49 | 2016-06-09 21:39:29 | C | D |

This is what I would like to achieve:

| Pickup time | Dropoff time | Pickup location | Dropoff location | Car # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-06-09 21:06:36 | 2016-06-09 21:13:08 | A | B | 1 |
| 2016-06-09 21:13:31 | 2016-06-09 21:23:59 | A | C | 2 |
| 2016-06-09 21:13:45 | 2016-06-09 21:24:29 | B | C | 1 |
| 2016-06-09 21:15:33 | 2016-06-09 21:44:31 | A | B | 3 |
| 2016-06-09 21:24:49 | 2016-06-09 21:39:29 | C | D | 2 |

Comment: How about timeframe? Which time should we look for to see if it's within 2 minutes

Comment: It would be between the dropoff time and the following pickup times available. So, if car 1 ends at 21:13:08, then we allow for 2 minutes for the next pick up time. It would have to occur before 21:15:08.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data.table approach, using a threshold of 120 seconds

```
library(data.table)

# Set threshold (in seconds)
threshold = 120

# Get the car identifier
result=melt(
  setDT(df)[,trip:=.I][df, on=.(`Dropoff location`=`Pickup location`), nomatch=0] %>% 
    .[between(`i.Pickup time`-`Dropoff time`,0,threshold),.(trip,i.trip)] %>% 
    .[,car:=.I],id.vars = "car",value.name="trip"
)[,variable:=NULL][df, on="trip"]

# add any other single-instance cars
result[is.na(car),car:=seq(max(result$car,na.rm=T)+1, length.out = result[is.na(car),.N])]
```

Output:

```
     car  trip         Pickup time        Dropoff time Pickup location Dropoff location
   <int> <int>              <POSc>              <POSc>          <char>           <char>
1:     1     1 2016-06-09 21:06:36 2016-06-09 21:13:08               A                B
2:     2     2 2016-06-09 21:13:31 2016-06-09 21:23:59               A                C
3:     1     3 2016-06-09 21:13:45 2016-06-09 21:26:29               B                C
4:     3     4 2016-06-09 21:15:33 2016-06-09 21:44:31               A                B
5:     2     5 2016-06-09 21:24:49 2016-06-09 21:39:29               C                D
```

Input:

```
structure(list(`Pickup time` = structure(c(1465506396, 1465506811, 
1465506825, 1465506933, 1465507489), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), `Dropoff time` = structure(c(1465506788, 1465507439, 
1465507589, 1465508671, 1465508369), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), `Pickup location` = c("A", "A", "B", "A", 
"C"), `Dropoff location` = c("B", "C", "C", "B", "D")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you for your input @langtang! how would you edit this if instead of pick up location, you had pickup latitude and longitude in 2 separate columns? (and the same for dropoff location).

Comment: perhaps just change the join criteria.. i.e. `on=.(drop_lat=pick_lat, drop_long = pick_long)`??

Comment: Thank you again for the tip @langtang. When I run the above code with `on=.(drop_lat=pick_lat, drop_long = pick_long)` I get `Error: The Between function only applies to numeric vectors`. My time variables are POSIXct, and long/lat variables are num, which should allow for this to work. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: i'm not sure.. instead of using `between()`, perhaps just use directly.. i.e instead of `between(x,5,8)` use `x>=5 & x<=8`.. Perhaps that will resolve it